# Deduction of Newton's third law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, coulombs-law

We know that Newton's third law only works for Coloumb and Gravitational forces and all others derived from it, like friction, normal force, tension, etc.

Thus it was my belief that since both Coloumb and Gravitational forces are such that each particle applies same force on another and in opposite direction to the line joining them, that third law is a consequence of these, that is if we know these two laws we can deduce 3rd Law.

But now if I think about it (and this is purely my speculation) that the laws of these forces would be found experimentally by using the third law, thus my reasoning of deducing third law becomes wrong.

So is this view correct that third law can be deduced from expressions of fundamental forces?

Comment: newton's third law isn't even a "law"as it gets violated pretty easily in electromagnetic interactions (*footnote: section 1.2, Classical Mechanics by H. Goldstein*). You say "forces would be found experimentally by using third law" I don't think that's the case, you use instruments in a lab to test a theory. If experiments agree with the theory, the predictions of the law are verified. If you simply use the third law to find forces in a lab you don't need the lab to begin with. Just use pen and paper.

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on what  you mean by finding forces experimentally in the lab using third law.

Comment: @aman Newton's third law is a fundamental law of mechanics and claiming "it isn't even a law" is misleading to say the least. The fact that it can be "violated" in, as you alluded to, non-reciprocal interactions, doesn't invalidate this law. It just means that there are specific nonequilibrium physical systems where we need to look deeper at what's happening.

Comment: @josephh that's why i put law in quotation marks, just a matter of book-keeping. I was simply trying to shed some light on the fact that third law isn't always valid as one might think. As OP was trying to deduce third  law in a lab I just pointed out some cases where he won't be able to. Perhaps saying "it's not even a law" was a bit harsh.